# GUI miner not working properly (slush's pool)

Tags: security, miner-configuration, gpu-mining

I'm trying to mine for slush's pool with GUIminer. The miner says that I am mining, and gives me a mhash number, but says that no matter how long I mine, I still have 0 shares.
[image]

The pool says that I have no mhash input to the pool.
[image]

Thanks in advance, bark

Comment: What's the longest you have been running the miner?

Comment: I've been running it for about 2 hours

Comment: Ok, according to the mining calculators you should find a share at difficulty on average once every 20 minutes. Unless its a fluke and you simply have bad luck, there really is something wrong here.

Comment: You're trying to mine bitcoin with your CPU? It's like cutting diamonds with a sardine.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you really don't want to be mining with your cpu.  If this was with your gpu and this was happening, your debug output would probably involve a "check your hardware" error like the one many people got from the newest AMD SDK.  That is fixed by rolling back drivers to the best compatible set.

You should look at the console by going to the menu bar: View > Show Console.  Click the tab that pops up named Console and perhaps post a screenshot of that.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the server as "other" and typing in stratum.bitcoin.cz as the host and 3333 as the port.